# Can't solve Fatal Exception:Value for message cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting this error on my react native application. Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Value for message cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String
It does not show up that often. But about %10 of my users gets it.

I thought the problem was from the json. But i'm not sure.

```
async function getCountry() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=country',
    );
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

```
 let countryName="";
    await getCountry().then((data)=> { countryName= data.country}).catch(()=> countryName="")


    var user = {
      _id : "user:"+email,
      name: name,
      photo: image,
      email: email,
      country:countryName
      };
```

I need to fix the crash.

Comment: Is it possible that the API returns an empty string ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Should i also check if the api is returning 404 error?

Comment: My guess is that the API responds with 200, but the data returned is empty. As a result its unable to parse the Response